# Align Text Inside A Inline-Block Div? CSS

Tags: css, block, inline, text-alignment

I am trying to align a group of text, including p and h5 html elements. I am using inline-block display type to get the text to be on the same line for the titles. If the aligning with this display type is not possible it would be helpful if you could provide a alternate way the 3 titles on the same line. Here is my code:

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.column,
.columns {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
/* For devices larger than 400px */

@media (min-width: 400px) {
  .container {
    width: 85%;
    padding: 0;
  }
}
/* For devices larger than 550px */

@media (min-width: 550px) {
  .container {
    width: 80%;
  }
  .column,
  .columns {
    margin-left: 4%;
  }
  .column:first-child,
  .columns:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  .one-third.column {
    width: 30.6666666667%;
  }
  #importantpeople {
    text-align: center;
  }
  #manager-1 {
    font-weight: 500;
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: -2px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  #manager-2 {
    font-weight: 500;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
  }
  #manager-3 {
    font-weight: 500;
    text-align: right;
    margin-right: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: right;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="seven columns" id="seven-cols">
      <h4 id="aboutus">About Us</h4>
      <p>TheVersionArts is a private design studio. We were founded in the winter of 2014. We connect clients to the designers they need. Our goal is to serve high quality design at an affordable price through the internet. We strive to impress our clients.
        If you want to be apart of this movement then sign up now!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row" id="importantpeople">
    <h4 id="managers-head">Our Managers</h4>
    <div class="one-third.column" id="screamer">
    </div>
    <div class="one-third.column" id="kinzu">
    </div>
    <div class="one-third.column" id="swezii">
    </div>
    <h5 id="manager-1">Screamer</h5>
    <h5 id="manager-2">KINZU</h5>
    <h5 id="manager-3">Swezii</h5>
    <p>Just a guy chilling on his computer creating works of art for people</p>
    <p>I am a guy who loves to get the things in my head onto paper. I have some great ideas that will blow your minds! Get ready!</p>
    <p>I love Web, App and other designing. It is my goal to get rid of bad design in my city.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**So my question is how to I align #screamer to the left, #kinzu to the center and #swezii to the right when it is on the same line?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **float: left** for the #manager-1 and **float: right** for the #manager-3.
This pulls the *Screamer* to the left and the *Swezii* to the right while *KINZU* is in the center.

```
#manager-1 {
    font-weight: 500;
    float: left;
    margin-left: -2px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
}

#manager-2 {
    font-weight: 500;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}

#manager-3 {
    font-weight: 500;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: On the same line? I was doing this but it did not work. They where on separate lines if I removed the display:inline-block; but would not align if I used float and display:inline-block.

Comment: This worked after removing margins and changing them a bit. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Change the Margins to 20%, and invert the direction you have them set as, make sure you use % not px for the margins.

```
#manager-1 {
    font-weight: 500;
    text-align: left;
    margin-right: 20%;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
  }
#manager-2 {
    font-weight: 500;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
  }
#manager-3 {
  font-weight: 500;
  text-align: right;
  margin-left: 20%;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right;
  }
```

Comment: Seems to be working but how would I get the text directly underneath the images as seen here: http://prntscr.com/77yh9y

Comment: The easiest way to do that is replace the <h5> with an <img> tag. Have the Image contain the picture u want AND the Name underneath it.